# I am Getting an Error Whilst Mocking a Function Using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I am writing my fist mock function. I am getting an error on mocking function, if I console the item I am getting action={[Function]}.
Can anyone help me to mock this function?

Error:

```
Expected: [Function mockConstructor]
Received: [Function anonymous]
```

My code:

```
export const transform = React.memo<transform Props>((props) => (
<Container
 actions={[
  transformitemLeft(
    'Clean',
    () => {
      props.onschedule()
    },
  ),
 />
```

Test case:

```
const onscheduleMock = jest.fn()
test('Actions', () => {
const item = render().find(transform)
expect(item.at(0).prop('action')).toBe(onscheduleMock )
})
```

Comment: How do you pass your mocked function into the props of your `transform` component ? It doesn't look like it's passed at all; that's probably why you have an anonymous function error...

Comment: @Orlyyn what should i do with this then

should i check expect(onscheduleMock ).toHaveBeenCalled()

Comment: Yes, this would check that your mock function is actually called! Which is what you want in the end right ?
However, it will work when its call is triggered. In your example, it would be when the `transformitemLeft` is triggered in your `Container` component. So first, you'll need to trigger the `transformitemLeft` before testing your mock function call.

Comment: And if you succeed it triggering the `transformitemLeft ` function, I still don't see how your function is passed as props to your component...

Comment: @Orlynn Can i get one example or an snippet for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment, here is a way to verify a mock function call with `.toHaveBeenCalled()`, using a functional React component:

```js
// Component

const MyButton = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <button
      id="step-section-save-button"
      className="button-save"
      data-testid="save-button"
      onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
    >
      Save
    </button>
  );
}

export default MyButton;
```

```js
// test file
import React from 'react';
import { render, getByText, fireEvent, getByTestId } from '@testing-library/react';

it('should trigger the handleSubmit function', () => {
  const mockHandleSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { container } = render(
    <MyButton handleSubmit={() => mockHandleSubmit()} />  // mockedFunction is passed as props
  );

  const buttonComponent = getByTestId(container, "save-button");
  fireEvent.click(buttonComponent); // Fire the event that will trigger my mocked function

  expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```